# How to migrate WCF Service to .NET Core class library application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to migrate old project from **.NET Framework** to .**NET Core 2.1** that creates **Host Server** and **WebHttpBinding** that is not longer supported by .NET Core *(only client is supported)*. I find some libraries like **SoapCore** but I couldn't find quite exact methods/objects for my case. Is there a library that can replace those objects?

```
public WebHttpServiceHost(IConfig config, ILogger logger, IHttpWebService service)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Address = new Uri("http://" + new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, config.Service.HttpPort));
        Host = new ServiceHost(service, Address);

        var webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding
        {
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue,
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };

        var endPoint = Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IHttpWebService),
            CreateGzipBinding(webHttpBinding),
            Address);

        endPoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        endPoint.Behaviors.Add(new ContentEncodingBehavior(new Dictionary<HttpResponseHeader, string>
        {
            { HttpResponseHeader.ContentEncoding, "gzip" },
            { HttpResponseHeader.ContentType, "application/bson" }
        }));
    }

 public TcpServiceHost(ILogger logger, IConfig config, ILiveStreamService service)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Config = config;
        Address = new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://", IPAddress.Any, config.Service.TcpPort));

        Host = new ServiceHost(service, Address);

        // Host behaviors
        Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior());
        Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
        {
            MaxConcurrentSessions = Config.Service.LiveStreamMaxConcurrentSessions,
        });

        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(ILiveStreamService),
            new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None),
            string.Empty);

        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
            MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
            "mex");
    }
```

Comment: You are right. Currently core does not support WCF server-side, and SoapCore is not an official Microsoft library. Currently core only supports WCF clients, and WCF clients are also restricted in core. If you want to use WCF, I still recommend you to use the .net framework.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use .net framework because the application must run on Linux :( and with . framework the application can run only on Windows

Comment: This is a tricky question. The current solution is to use the .net framework to call WCF, and this project must be run in windows.

Comment: Yeah but we get a requirement from customer to migrate it to .net core so they can run it on Linux and we can not go around this. But I was thinking if its possible to rewrite that communication to REST and just abandon that WCF?

Comment: If the WCF server-side must be created with core, this requirement cannot be achieved at present.

Comment: We find that gRPC is able to do what we need so we decided to rewrite entire communication between services

Comment: gRpc is  a good choice, good luck for you.